# Java mail : receiving email body as .htm file attachment along with attachment and body

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

Dears,

Facing an issue mail body duplicating in mobile when sending email using java mail (Microsoft Exchange server). Sending email body and pdf as attachment but when it customer receives the mail in inbox the email body content is duplicating (twice), also its sending PDF and one .htm file as attachment. Due to .htm file the email body is coming as twice. How to avoid this duplication body in mail. Below is the code used to send an email.  This issue not happening in browser based email clients, Its happening only in mobile.

Setting email body (html content) as below

```
import javax.mail.Message;
Message  msg = new SMTPMessage(session);
MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
MimeBodyPart mbp = null;
mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
mbp.setContent("Hi, This is a test.", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
mp.addBodyPart(mbp);
```

setting pdf as attachment

```
 MimeBodyPart mbp = null;
 ByteArrayDataSource xfds3 = null;
 mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
 byte[] b = //PDF byte array
 xfds3 = new ByteArrayDataSource(b, "application/pdf");
 mbp.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(xfds3));
 String maskName = maskingNo(fileName, prop);
 mbp.setFileName(maskName);
 mp.addBodyPart(mbp); 
 msg.setContent(mp);
 transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
```

Can anyone help how to solve this issue?

**Output is coming in mail body:**

Hi,
This is a test.

Hi,
This is a test

Comment: All mobile clients or only one?  Which one?  Is the message being read from Exchange or from some other mail serve?  If you read the message using JavaMail, does it have the structure and content you expect?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the format you are sending and what the client is showing or build based on that.

There are:

- plain/text(no fancy Styling)
- text/html
- Richtext (should normally be avoid, due to the winmail.dat issue)
- multipart/mixed

So a possible email could have the source:

```
  multipart/mixed
    multipart/alternative (holding the two forms of the body part)
      text/plain
      text/html
    text/plain or image/gif (the attachment)
```

[image]

However depending on the mail client this email might only show the plain text elements and no "structure" at all. Such stuff above if often used to have some compatibility in place, so if the email client couldn´t handle HTML emails the user can still read the plain text. If the client couldn´t understand HTML (or if the multipart section is broken) a HTML content might be changed into an attachment (might be your issue).

So your question isn´t that easy to answer as we:

- Do not know which Exchange Server send out those emails
- Which Format is used to send out the emails
- If something is changing the format on the way to the sender
- Which client the receiver is used

Further troubleshooting must be done on your side:

- Is that happening when you send an email to an internal user
- Is that happening when you send an email to Gmail, Outlook.com, ...
- Is that happening when you send the email without HTML content (only attachment)?
- Is your multipart section correct? Check some examples on the internet for example [here](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/javamail/send-e-mail-with-attachment-in-java):

  package net.codejava.mail;

  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.Date;
  import java.util.Properties;

  import javax.mail.Authenticator;
  import javax.mail.Message;
  import javax.mail.MessagingException;
  import javax.mail.Multipart;
  import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
  import javax.mail.Session;
  import javax.mail.Transport;
  import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
  import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
  import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
  import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
  import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

  public class EmailAttachmentSender {

  ```
  public static void sendEmailWithAttachments(String host, String port,
          final String userName, final String password, String toAddress,
          String subject, String message, String[] attachFiles)
          throws AddressException, MessagingException {
      // sets SMTP server properties
      Properties properties = new Properties();
      properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
      properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
      properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
      properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
      properties.put("mail.user", userName);
      properties.put("mail.password", password);

      // creates a new session with an authenticator
      Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
          public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
              return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
          }
      };
      Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

      // creates a new e-mail message
      Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
      InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
      msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
      msg.setSubject(subject);
      msg.setSentDate(new Date());

      // creates message part
      MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
      messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "text/html");

      // creates multi-part
      Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
      multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

      // adds attachments
      if (attachFiles != null && attachFiles.length > 0) {
          for (String filePath : attachFiles) {
              MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();

              try {
                  attachPart.attachFile(filePath);
              } catch (IOException ex) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
              }

              multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
          }
      }

      // sets the multi-part as e-mail's content
      msg.setContent(multipart);

      // sends the e-mail
      Transport.send(msg);

  }

  /**
   * Test sending e-mail with attachments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      // SMTP info
      String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
      String port = "587";
      String mailFrom = "your-email-address";
      String password = "your-email-password";

      // message info
      String mailTo = "your-friend-email";
      String subject = "New email with attachments";
      String message = "I have some attachments for you.";

      // attachments
      String[] attachFiles = new String[3];
      attachFiles[0] = "e:/Test/Picture.png";
      attachFiles[1] = "e:/Test/Music.mp3";
      attachFiles[2] = "e:/Test/Video.mp4";

      try {
          sendEmailWithAttachments(host, port, mailFrom, password, mailTo,
              subject, message, attachFiles);
          System.out.println("Email sent.");
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          System.out.println("Could not send email.");
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line:

`mbp.setContent("Hi, This is a test.", "text/html; charset=utf-8");`

Write this:

`mbp.setContent("Hi, This is a test.", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");`